# Editing Song Artist Name and Song Title According to the Song ID

Tags: java, android-studio, class

I have 3 classes. I would like to pass a new value when I click the button in Edit Activity

Firstly, This is my Song class where I declared my variables

```
public class Song {

private String id;
private String title;
private String artist;
private String fileLink;
private double songLength;
private String coverArt;
private String videoLink;

public Song(String i, String t, String a, String f,double sl, String ca,String v) {
    id = i;
    title = t;
    artist = a;
    fileLink = f;
    songLength = sl;
    coverArt = ca;
    videoLink = v;
}

public String getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(String newId)
{

    id = newId;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String newTitle)
{
    title = newTitle;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}
public void setArtist(String newArtist)
{
    artist = newArtist;
}

public String getFileLink()
{
    return fileLink;
}

public String getCoverArt()
{
    return coverArt;
}

public String getVideoLink()
{
    return videoLink;
}

}
```

> These are the hard coded title values

```
public class SongCollection {
public Song[] songs = new Song[3];
public SongCollection()
{
    prepareSongs();
}

private void prepareSongs()
{
    Song theWayYouLookTonight = new Song("S1001", "The Way You Look Tonight","Michael Buble","a5b8972e764025020625bbf9c1c2bbb06e394a60?cid=null",4.39,"michael_buble_collection","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKpNL2Nm9SM");
    Song billieJean = new Song("S1002","Billie Jean","Michael Jackson","4eb779428d40d579f14d12a9daf98fc66c7d0be4?cid=null",5.45,"billie_jean","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi_XLOBDo_Y");
    Song outinSpace = new Song("S1003","Out in Space","Whiz Khalifa","3d691281fae7d4ba8c5907887d2a31ce064891b3?cid=null",2.83,"wiz_khalifa","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNsWBRNLLjc");
    songs[0] = theWayYouLookTonight;
    songs[1] = billieJean;
    songs[2] = outinSpace;
}
}
```

}

> This is my Edit Activity app and I want the button to set the new song artist name and song title as the new value

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button submitBtn;
EditText et;
EditText ea;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
    et = findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    ea = findViewById(R.id.editArtist);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // I do not know how to pass the values in the constructor
            Song newSong = new Song();
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.class);
            newSong.setArtist(ea.getText().toString());
            newSong.setTitle(et.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });



}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include that I would want the new values to match the song ID, 
For example, Song ID S1001, Title, The Way You Look Tonight : Artist: Michael Buble to Song ID S1001, New Title: FavSong1,New Artist Michael OGBuble

Comment: Do you want to edit an existing song or change a song that exists already?

Comment: I want to edit an existing song name and title

Comment: Well, you need to access the songs array and then change the entry inside of it. If you dont know how to do it, you should either learn some more of the basics of Java or we could talk via Discord and I explain it to you. But I would recommend to follow some tutorials to learn the basics

Comment: I know how to edit the hard coded ones but I do not know how to set a new value

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand what you want to do.. on the submit button click would you like to pass what the user have inputted inside the edit texts to the next activity? and there what?

Comment: Okay. Basically, you first need to identify the item you want to change. So do u give the User an input for which Song he wants to edit?